# Creating SQL like table and sharing them in Android

Tags: android, sql, api, google-api, synchronization

I am developing an app on Android platform where I need to create a SQL like table that contains multiple records,and that is synced and shared with the other users.

What is the easiest way to implement this functionality. Which API should I be using?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "shared with other users"?

Comment: If you plan to work online, the best option is a server running some webservices.

Comment: I mean the same table will be seen by the other users, if one user makes a change in the table the others will also be seeing the change

Comment: Users on same device can access it

Comment: Best way really depends on a lot of details of your app.  But you're going to need a central server with the authoritative data sending push notifications down to the device.  Really what you have is a cache coherency problem, I suggest you study up on that.  There's no simple answer to give you.

Comment: You mean you want to create a database **from within** that will be able to be queried by other applications in the same device?

Comment: The database will be a shared one,but each user will be able to add,edit,delete records at their end.